# Having hyper-referenced items for the symbols in a nomenclature table

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, longtable, classicthesis, nomenclature

I am trying to replicate the following picture, with some modifications, in my thesis which shows a nomenclature in a long table format. I want to have this along with `classicthesis` package version `2012/08/12 v4.1`. The version of `nomentbl` I am using is `22006/04/14 v0.4`.

[image]

I would also like to have the reference in the nomenclature such that they are hyper-referenced. I mean, I would like to have a reference such that when I click on that, it takes me to the definition of that symbol. In addition, as can be seen in the above picture, some of the symbols have page reference, section reference, and figure reference and some of the symbols does not have any reference, for example symbol `g`, gravitational constant. How can I define such an entry? Could someone please help me how I should modify the following MWE to achieve such a result?

```
\documentclass[
                %twoside, 
                openright,
                titlepage, numbers=noenddot, headinclude,%1headlines,
                footinclude=true, cleardoublepage=empty,
                BCOR=30mm, paper=letter, fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
                dottedtoc,
                ngerman, american, % Languages
                ]{scrreprt} 

\PassOptionsToPackage{%
                    eulerchapternumbers,
                    listings,
                    %drafting,
                    pdfspacing,
                    %floatperchapter,
                    %linedheaders,%
                    subfig,
                    beramono,
                    % eulermath, % This changes the font for math equations.
                    parts}{classicthesis}

\usepackage{tabularx} % Better tables
\usepackage{chngcntr}

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} % Increase table row height
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % To be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption} 
\captionsetup{format=hang, font=small} 


\usepackage[position=t,singlelinecheck=off,font={it}]{subfig}

\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex,hyperfootnotes=false,pdfpagelabels}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}  % backref linktocpage pagebackref
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\pdfadjustspacing=1

\hypersetup{
            colorlinks=true, linktocpage=true, pdfstartpage=1, pdfstartview=FitV,
            breaklinks=true, pdfpagemode=UseNone, pageanchor=true, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
            plainpages=false, bookmarksnumbered, bookmarksopen=true, bookmarksopenlevel=1,
            hypertexnames=true, pdfhighlight=/O, %
}   


\usepackage{classicthesis}

\counterwithin{figure}{chapter}

\usepackage[refpage, refeq]{nomentbl}
\makenomenclature
\begin{document}
\section*{Main equations}
\begin{equation}
a=\frac{N}{A}g
\end{equation}%
\nomenclature[Aa]{$a$}{The number of angels per unit area}{}{}
\nomenclature[An]{$N$}{The number of angels per needle point}{}{}
\nomenclature[Aa]{$A$}{The area of the needle point}{}{}
\nomenclature[Ag]{$g$}{Gravitational constant = 9.86 ms$^{-2}$}{}{}
The equation $\sigma = m a$%
\nomenclature[Gs]{$\sigma$}{The total mass of angels per unit area}{}{}
\nomenclature[Am]{$m$}{The mass of one angel}{}{}
follows easily.
\printnomenclature
\end{document}
```

Here is the page 1 of the above document.

[image]

And here is the page 2.

[image]

As I mentioned earlier, I would also like to suppress referencing for constant `g`, gravitational constant. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

You will need to replace every occurrence of the symbol you want to anchor with (at least) a new command, such as `$\ha$` instead of `$a$`.  You will need to also assign a unique name to each symbol and set up the definition as a `\hypertarget`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nomencl}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makenomenclature

\newcommand{\ha}{\hyperlink{nomen.a}{a}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\ha=\frac{N}{A}g
\end{equation}%

\nomenclature{$a$}{\hypertarget{nomen.a}{The number of angels per unit area}}

\lipsum[1-3]
\printnomenclature

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I want to have the hyperlink in nomenclature page. So when you click on the reference such as `page 1`, it takes you to page one where the symbol is defined.

Comment: Try it now.  I moved the target inside the definition.

Comment: Other than misspelling \hypertarget, it worked fine for me.  You just have to zoom in far enough.